# Pandas - Transform DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame:

```
   ID  Y-M  Question Score
0   1  2020-1   A    0.1
1   1  2019-2   B    0.5
2   2  2019-5   A    0.7
3   2  2020-2   B    0.9
```

I would like to transform to the dataframe like so

```
             2019-2             2019-5            2020-1       2020-2
             A     B            A    B            A    B       A     B          
ID    
    1        NAN   0.5          NAN  NAN          0.1   NAN    NAN    NAN                                          
    2        NAN   NAN          0.7  NAN          NAN.  NAN    NAN    0.9
```

Is it possible? If yes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pivot_table` as follows.

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'Score', index = 'ID', columns = ['Y-M', 'Question'])
```

The result is

[image]